# gen/kaa_remote_control_ecf.h: No such file or directory

Tags: iot, esp8266, kaa

I'm Using Kaa Opensource IoT platform to control GPIO of ESP8266. Im using ESP-01 module for this project. Im using [this](https://github.com/vadimol/kaa_gpio_esp8266_example) example. Getting error while compiling the code

```
[ 93%] Building C object CMakeFiles/demo_client_s.dir/src/kaa_demo.c.obj
/home/sse/Kaa/ESP8266/kaa_gpio_esp8266_example/src/kaa_demo.c:23:40: fatal error: gen/kaa_remote_control_ecf.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gen/kaa_remote_control_ecf.h>
                                        ^
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/demo_client_s.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/demo_client_s.dir/src/kaa_demo.c.obj' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/demo_client_s.dir/src/kaa_demo.c.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:69: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/demo_client_s.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/demo_client_s.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

there is a file missing named `gen/kaa_remote_control_ecf.h` Im not able to locate this file anywhere.

Is there any other way to find this file?

I'm using latest Kaa SDK 0.10.

Comment: According to information in the github README, did you "Download and untar the C SDK from the Kaa server"? And did you follow all the steps described here: https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Using-Kaa-endpoint-SDKs/C/SDK-ESP8266/ ?

Comment: @DaltonCézane yes I followed each and every steps correctly. I have run sample kaa application on ESP8266 which just print "Hello Kaa". Then after understanding  the process I proceeded for GPIO example.